# Crashlytics build script fails on Xcode Server CI

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, crashlytics, xcode-server

I'm running Xcode Server 3.0.1 on an iMac, also hosting the Git project repository, and Xcode 5.0.2 on MacBookPro. I used the Crashlytics app to get the framework integrated into the project and the dashboard account set up.

The bot build integration fails with the error:

> /bin/sh -c /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5ebae11-195e-195e-6a5e-4d0088985621/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SparrowEDIS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SparrowEDIS.build/Release-iphoneos/SparrowEDIS.build/Script-07EC5E4F18376B9B00BF4303.sh
>
> 2013-11-16 01:06:48.173 run[27823:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3
>   2013-11-16 01:06:48.201 run[27823:507] ERROR: unable to write directory for object store.
>   2013-11-16 01:06:48.220 run[27823:507] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “builds” in the folder “5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810”." UserInfo=0x100301c20
>
> NSFilePath=/var/teamsserver/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/builds, NSUnderlyingError=0x100300d90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"
>
> 2013-11-16 01:06:48.233 run[27823:507] Unable to create directory at path /var/teamsserver/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/builds/86837619-9986-420B-BA7A-D7E44885C461 
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “86837619-9986-420B-BA7A-D7E44885C461” in the folder “builds”." UserInfo=0x100215330
>
> NSFilePath=/var/teamsserver/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac/5b91b14e832a7b1c29441ec5ba109810/builds/86837619-9986-420B-BA7A-D7E44885C461, NSUnderlyingError=0x1002153f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"
>
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

The last build phase is the Crashlytics "run" script:

> ./Vendor/Crashlytics/Crashlytics.framework/run a5c09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4085

Has anyone run into this? I'm at a loss. Thanks.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, the problem turned out to be related to the Crashlytics app, which should not be installed on your Xcode server. I was prompted to install it when troubleshooting another issue and it was conflicting with the command line builds that Xcode Server is running.

1. Quit Xcode and the Crashlytics app.
2. Delete the Crashlytics app.
3. Trigger an Integration (and cross your fingers).

Comment: thanks, this fixed it for me too. Also, while futzing with schemes and build settings in setting up the bots, I had removed and forgotten to add back in the Run Script build phase which uploads the dSYM.

Comment: What if your OS X Server is running on your development device? I am having this issue but run my server on my actual macbook that is used for development. Also using cocoapods version of Fabric/Crashlytics so not sure if thats an issue to (even with updated path using $(PODS_ROOT))